# recyclerview notifyDataSetChanged stop detecting end of recyclerview for pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview and definitely an adapter related to it.
but the problem that am facing when i am calling notifyDataSetChanged the recyclerview will not be able to detect the end of recyclerview is there any possible fix for it ?

Comment: Please post your code!!

Comment: i have adapter that implements an interface adapter.setLoadMore(here it calls the http service to append data to the list) inside of it calls adapter.notifydataSetChange when it's called it will stop detecting the end of recyclerview